# "Redirect" class member functions?

Tags: c++, templates

Basically I found myself today writing lots of code like below:

```
#define VAL_1 0
#define VAL_2 1

class A {

public:
  void memberA();
  void memberB();

  ...

  void write(uin32_t address);

}

void
A::
memberA() {

  this->write(VAL_1);

}

void
A::
memberB() {

  this->write(VAL_2);

}

...
```

So basically, I have "pretty" names `memberA`, `memberB` for some task that really only does call the same function `write` with a different argument. The values `VAL_0` and `VAL_1` are not necessarily known to code using my class. Neither is the implementation detail behind `memberA` or `memberB`, although `write`might be going public at some point.

Basically, now I'm repeating the same line of code `this->write(...)` over and over again. I'm looking for a solution that bypasses this step and calls the respective write immediately. A kind of passing on of the function arguments somewhat like a C++ constructor from a base class, possibly with matching arguments:

```
#define VAL_1 0
#define VAL_2 1

class A {

public:
  bool memberA() : write(VAL_1);
  bool memberB() : write(VAL_2);

  ...

  bool write(uin32_t address);

}
```

I'm wondering whether there might be something in Boost.Bind or some clever template-coding that lets me achieve this kind or thing?

Thanks,

FRob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without fully understanding what you are after (I got confused about the last part involving constructors), I think you might be trying a little too hard to make the syntax easier on your clients.

... how about simply:

```
class A {
public:
    enum Value {val1, val2, val3, val4, etc};
    bool write(Value val);
};
```

It's good that you are trying to establish an easier syntax, but you also have to avoid the danger of monolithism. Monolithic classes are something that I strongly believe is one of the most common mistakes in object-oriented design. Sutter goes into this in detail in `C++ Coding Standards` and on gotw: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm.

*If you have a class with 100 member functions, you probably have about 80 too many.*

^ Think about this statement for a while. When you have so many functions, your classes tend to become increasingly hard to manage. It also invites other developers to just keep adding more and more to your class so that its design is never finalized. The result is the never-ending class that just grows and grows with each development cycle with no end in sight. That can easily become a source of bugs, inefficiencies, constant public interface revisions, unit test breakages, and it can go against the general reuse and flexibility of your class. When you have a separate function per value you can pass to another function, you're dangerously treading into that territory.

Trying too hard to avoid *syntactical redundancy* is usually a mistake. Unfortunately C++ just requires more lengthy syntax in some cases (getting much better with C++11). What you should try to optimize away is *logical redundancy*. Here calling write method with various values involves no logical redundancy, and the syntactical overhead is barely more than calling different functions for each value you can possibly pass to write.

If these functions do nothing more than simplify the syntax of passing various values, you have to come to the realization that you are also bloating the class's public interface with a whole lot more functions that, if you are in a production environment, you will likely have to document and teach individually. Strive for doing more with less and I think you'll be much better off.

Try to keep this aspect of monolithism in mind as a priority. You might even go so far as to hoist the named constants out of the class definition as non-members, like so:

```
class A {
    bool write(uint32_t address);
};

// elsewhere
static const uint32_t address_val1 = ...;
static const uint32_t address_val2 = ...;
static const uint32_t address_val3 = ...;
```

There's actually nothing wrong with this design and, in fact, it has more desirable engineering characteristics than the one where you have more class members as it's completely decoupled from your class, making the maintenance of that class easier, its interface simpler to teach and document, and more likely to meet a state of reasonable completion.

Comment: Well, I understand that. However, `memberA` and `memberB` will have different implementations in a child class, so with your solution I cannot overwrite these anymore...

Comment: My suggestion is just make *write* public instead of having memberA and memberB functions at all, as in completely remove those functions in favor of just letting the client write my_a.write(address_val1), e.g. BTW, are you trying to do this as an optimization? If so, memberA and memberB are typically going to have zero overhead after a compiler applies its optimizations so the cost of writing those functions from a processor efficiency standpoint is effectively *zero*. If you find it tedious writing those functions, then that's a different thing.. but using macros to generate your ...

Comment: class methods is generally going to be considered a hack. It wouldn't pass code review in a normal production environment to shorthand something which is already a one-liner like this through the preprocessor.

Comment: I understood your suggestion the first time. However, your solution doesn't work in my scenario. The distinctive function that `memberA` implements will not be `write` in a child class, so I need to have those members... Yes, this was mainly about saving a) work writing the code and b) maybe optimize the compile outputs. So you're saying there will be no overhead? If that's the case, that'd be great :)

Comment: @FRob I'm very confused. You mean memberA is intended to be a virtual (overridable) function? Its behavior could change depending on what inherits from A?

Comment: @FRob there is typically no overhead for direct function calls. If there's anything that optimizing C++ compilers have done indisputably well for over a decade, it's inlining function calls (see benchmarks for std::sort vs. qsort as an example), so you should never look at a function as overhead. However, that is for direct function calls. If it's an indirect function call (exported function through shared library/DLL, virtual function, or function pointer), then there is runtime overhead that compilers generally can't optimize away.

Comment: Yes, specializations of my class will need to implement the members differently. Being a virtual function call anyway, I thought that this could somehow be redirected in my base class to the correct non-virtual function including a suitable argument...

Comment: @FRob I see.. at that point, I think we're back to my original advice: don't try too hard to avoid syntactical redundancy. We'll start becoming tempted to use things like macros which, as Stroustrup says, implies a defect of the programmer, program, or language. At best you are saving yourself a line of code by trying to reduce the code. Simply make memberA call write if it needs to. It won't incur any kind of performance penalty that alternative methods won't, so at best you're going out of your way to make minor syntactical reductions but at the cost of doing something ...

Comment: @FRob ... a bit exotic, unorthodox which will generally annoy your code readers.

Answer (score 4):

If you make your `memberX` functions inline in the class definition, and if you avoid the redundant `this` reference, then you don't have too much extra to write:

Your desired (incorrect) syntax:

```
bool memberA() : write(VAL_1);
```

The actual (correct) syntax:

```
bool memberA() { return write(VAL_1); }
```

If you want to minimize your repetitive code, you could use the pre-processor:

```
#define F(l, n) bool l() { return write(n); }
 F(memberA, VAL_1)
 F(memberB, VAL_2)
#undef F
```

Further, you could use the preprocessor token-pasting operator `##`:

```
#define F(l, n) bool member##l() { return write(VAL_##n); }
 F(A, 1)
 F(B, 2)
#undef F
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion. That's what I came up with as well, but I thought there just _had_ to be a way to be smarter about this. :/